# Is it possible to do command injection in os/exec Command method?

Tags: go

My goal is to understand whether it is safe to use the `Command` method from `os/exec` package. This is important because I process file from the internet. Do I need to sanitize the file before adding it to `exec.Command()` ?

What I've did:

1. Tried to use `&&`, it does not work.

```
    injection := "&& sh bash.sh"
    out, err := exec.Command("ls", injection).Output()
    fmt.Println(string(out), err)
```

bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Comment: You should not accept input from the internet and pass that to exec.Command unless you have analysed through and through whether that's safe. Passing it in a way that it will be used as a filename is often dangerous. As the filename could be `/dev/<anything>` or `/proc/self/<anything>` and if you read or write to those, you could be seriously breaking things, you could be corrupting memory, you could be hacked because you're overwriting process memory with malicious code, you could be having a denial of service attack because you're exhausting /dev/random, etc. etc.

Comment: - Never trust user input  
- Always convert to expected type (number to number, string to allowed format etc.)  
- oh, and never trust user input  

Maybe your given ONE example didn't work. It doesn't mean there is no workaround. Depending on executed command you can do ahrmful things. 

`ls` command is kinda not dangerous, but if you but `injection="-R"` you could read information that you didn't expect.

Maybe your command would be.. `myapp` and you can't inject `&& bla bla bla`. But maybe your app have `-o` option. I could use it to overwrie things.

Comment: `exec.Command()` is not a command line interpreter, nor is `ls`. To have `&&` work like that you would have to `Start()` `sh` or `bash` and write `ls && sh bash.sh\n` to the command's `stdin` stream.

Answer (score 1):

As you're only passing thes arguments to `ls`, and not to `sh`, there's not really any (obvious) opportunity for "command injection", but there's still plenty of opportunity for shennanigans.

At the very least, someone may be able to pass an argument that could crash `ls`, or cause your disks to thrash.  Arguments like `*/***********/****` or `../../../../../../../` or other odd combinations *might* do unexpected things. (I recall reading of web server exploits in the past using similar paths and causing a crash or hang of the system, trying to resolve an "impossible" path)

Further, depending on what you do with the result of `ls`, the user may be able to use this to learn priviledged information about your system. For example, someone might pass `/home` as an argument, and be returned a list of all users on your system.  If your service is running as root, they may be able to get other priveledged information from various points in `/var` or `/dev` or elsewhere.

And finally, if there's ever a bug in `ls`, someone may be able to take advantage of that to do, well, whatever the bug permits.